# Detect Ubuntu using perl

Tags: unity, perl

I am working on a perl script that must write configuration file. I need to know if the script is running on Ubuntu to set some Ubuntu-specific values (basically, disable the unified bar). The script cannot require any Perl packages that may not be present on user system.

How can I check if the system is Ubuntu or some other Linux distro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check contents of the `/etc/lsb-release` file.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer: https://metacpan.org/pod/Linux::Distribution

```
use Linux::Distribution qw(distribution_name);
print "Do your stuff here\n" if( distribution_name eq 'ubuntu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the output of `lsb_release` without parsing the file manually or loading an external module:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# ...
my $id = `lsb_release -si`;
chomp($id);
if($id eq "Ubuntu") {
    # set Ubuntu-specific values
}
# ...
```